# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PasswordResets - How to get a password reset token to save properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have attempting to create forgotten password functionality, but I'm running into an error where my Password Resets controller can't recognize the password reset token despite it being sent in the email.

Forgotten Password View

```
= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do
  .field
    = label_tag :email
    = text_field_tag :email, params[:email]
  .actions
    = submit_tag "Reset Password"
```

Password Resets Controller

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :notice => "Email Sent"
end
def edit
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
end
```

User Model

```
def send_password_reset
  self.password_reset_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!(:validate => false)
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end
```

The link I receive in my email is as follows

```
localhost:3000/password_resets/RrIf2WZB_C7iC3sCGNQHqg/edit
```

Everything seems to be functioning properly, I am sending an email with the above link, but when I click on it I get the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PasswordResets
Couldn't find User
```

I'm confused on how a token appears to be generated and sent with no errors with the save and yet it can't be found in the database. I'm probably being silly and overlooking something, but I can't figure it out.

Results for rake routes | grep password_reset

```
      password_resets GET                   /password_resets(.:format)                password_resets#index
                      POST                  /password_resets(.:format)                password_resets#create
   new_password_reset GET                   /password_resets/new(.:format)            password_resets#new
  edit_password_reset GET                   /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)       password_resets#edit
       password_reset GET                   /password_resets/:id(.:format)            password_resets#show
                      PATCH                 /password_resets/:id(.:format)            password_resets#update
                      PUT                   /password_resets/:id(.:format)            password_resets#update
                      DELETE                /password_resets/:id(.:format)            password_resets#destroy
```

UserMailer PasswordReset:

```
def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "#{user.username} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Password Reset")
end
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `UserMailer..password_reset` ?  I don't see a problem with your code and I'm wondering if the UserMailer might be generating a new password_reset_token...

Comment: Added, the UserMailer is very basic. The only other token I generate and email out is the password confirmation token, but I've tried to decouple those for testing purposes with still no luck. If I can't get it to work I might just try to redo everything from scratch.